# What will be runtime time complexity in terms of O(n) for following code snippet?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, code-analysis

I looked nested interdependent loops and I'm not able to figure out what will be the time complexity for following code:

```
void check(int n)
{ 
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i*i;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<j*j;k++)
            {    
                printf("HELLO");    //any O(1) task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in terms of `O(n)`?

Comment: it should be O(n3).  every for loop is looped for n times so n X n X n.

Comment: @RohitPadma how every loop is loop for `n` times? j loops for `O(n^2)` times itself, and k loops loops for another `O(j ^ 2)` where j at maximum is `O(n^2)`

Comment: I might be wrong but it should be O(n^7).

Comment: @RohitPadma No, it can't be N x N x N. It's a bit trickier.

Comment: @shole  My Bad - your right ! i have not checked in detail the loop constrain :(  so its First for loops for N time ,second for loops for N2 and Third for loops for N4. so its N X N2 X N4 = O(n^7).

Comment: @Nurzhan - Yeah your correct dude.  O (N^3 ) is wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

[image: sum]

[image: sum]

For calculating the time complexity we can ignore the lower order terms. The highest power of **'i'** is 6 so

[image: sum]

We know that :

[image: sum]

Hence

[image: sum]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is `O(N^7)` as the formula of the total steps is

[image]

I do not know how to resolve the summations as well so I ask a question here, and have a nice explanation from the accepted answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341496/how-to-resolve-this-kind-of-summation-formula/2341524#2341524

I do not know if it is appropriate to reference a question by me as an answer, but the post surely does answer your question and I believe it will help you to solve similar problems in the future

---

**EDITED:**

Thanks to @hk6279, I've overlooked the formula, it should be `1` instead of `k` in the deepest loop.

Yet the same principle of the reference should work as well.

Comment: The formula formation is incorrect, you should put 1 instead of k at the end.

Comment: Oops you are right, but the same argument and method can be applied, the answer is O(N^7) though, let me edit it

Answer (score 1):

Well, I thought it's too difficult, but no. Little mathematical support gives me perfect answer.

First of all, we've to consider how much times printf() function gets executed.
When i=1, it'll execute 1 time,
when i=2, same will execute 1+4+9+16 times, when i=3, it'll follow (1+4+9+16+25+36+49+64+81) times.

Remembering the pattern, when i = n, execution will be like (sum of squares of n^2 natural number)times.

Now finding time complexity:

(sum of 1 square terms) + (sum of 4 square terms) + (sum of 9 square terms) + ...... + (sum of n^2 square terms) = approximately (n^2)*(n^2 +1)*(2* n^2 +1)/6 + constants

-->obviously n^6 is the max term in the expression, O(n^6) will be time complexity

Comment: You formula  `(sum of 1 square terms) + (sum of 4 square terms) + (sum of 9 square terms) + ...... + (sum of n^2 square terms)` seems correct. But not final result. Look according to you, i th term `Ti = sum of  i*i square terms`, which is   `(i^2)(i^2 +1)(2* i^2 +1)/6`, and the final complexity will sum of all these terms(where i will var from 1 to n) which will give a term with power of `n` more than 6.

Comment: Moreover, your final result is `(n^2)(n^2 +1)(2* n^2 +1)/6 + constants`, here `constant` is `(sum of 1 square terms) + (sum of 4 square terms) + (sum of 9 square terms) + ...... + (sum of (n-1)^2 square terms)`, so it again depends on `n`. You just took last term into consideration and derived the complexity which is quite incorrect. Though you can explain me if I am incorrect somewhere.